# 405 – Method Not Allowed with @DELETE

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am working on (Maven Project) REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey. I am trying to delete a Module according to the passed **id**

```
@DELETE
@Path("delete/{id}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Module deleteModuleById(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
    return repository.delete(id);
}
```

I am getting 405 - Method not allowed from tomcat server, not sure what am I doing wrong.

This is the Delete Method:

```
public Module delete(long id) {
    EntityManager em = EM_FACTORY.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Module m = em.find(Module.class, id);
    if (m != null) {
        em.remove(m);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Provided id " + id + " does not exist!");
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    return m;
}
```

Postman request for all Module:
Postman request for delete module with id=1:

[image]

Project Structure:
[image][image]

Comment: `405 - Method not allowed` comes up when you send a request of the wrong type to the end point. What tool are you using to send requests to this endpoint?

Comment: I am using Postman

Comment: @Rody, show us the postman reequest

Comment: In addition to @BarHoshen, in the postman requests I don't you putting the param `id`.

Comment: @Rody, it says the error is `500` not, `405` ! Please if possible add which problem is for which request and the relevant logs too

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be ok. Check your Sending method. Please take into account that IllegalArgumentException will probably lead to 500 - Server error

Check via Curl

```
curl -X DELETE <YOUR HOST>/delete/123
```

Or check via any external resources like https://reqbin.com/, postman, etc.

Comment: @Rody it is also possible that you've mistaken with paths. Could you please show where have you set "api" and "modules" paths?

Comment: I did, but  I don't think that the problem is with the paths because I can create a new module with no problems

Comment: @Rody, your last DELETE request returned 500 - Internal server error. It means that the request was caught by a controller. Probably, your IllegalArgumentException was thrown. You can check it with temporary commenting "throw" to see that result is "OK" (200)

Comment: yes Thanks, but actually the problem was the module that I was trying to delete had FK Key referenced from another table so I wasn't able to delete it

Answer (score 0):

As your code seems fine and you haven't added your postman request, I assume you may have set the wrong method type in your request. you set your request like this image below:
[image: POSTMAN_DELETE_REQUEST]

Please, replace `base_url` and `your_id` with your actual values
**N.B: check the `DELETE` method I have set on left of the URL**

Comment: actually I am doing the same thing as you explained it, I edited the question, I added postman requests

Answer (score 0):

@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})

Postman automatically attaches the `Content-Type` header according to the settings of your request's body.
Your requests are set to HTML, not JSON.
It should give a different error, but this should cause an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

`405 Method not allowed` occurs when you try to `POST` while the method is `GET`, for example.

In the postman requests I don't see you putting the param `id`. So, the call you are making will look like `/api/modules/delete` while it should have been `/api/modules/delete/1`. And if there is a method like `api/modules/{x}`, it will call this method finally creating the `405`.